# How to make pre-build step script in Jenkins to skip the job and make it SUCCESS?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to run a pre-build step shell/perl in a Jenkins job, and given some conditions, I want it to skip the rest of the job, but still make it SUCCESS. Is there any way of doing that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it with a system Groovy script build step run via [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin):

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def thisBuild = thr?.executable

thisBuild.setResult(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
thisBuild.executor.interrupt(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
```

Warning: some plugins (most prominently Run Condition Plugin) do not handle 'interrupted build' gracefully (although they must, as far as I understand) and will fail the build if build steps 'belonging' to them run after that code.

Comment: That's nice, thanks. But I was wondering one thing: I just installed the plugin, and a very simple groovy script, but I am all the time getting, errors like Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/jelly/JellyException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/jelly/JellyException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyException
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE. *Which jars would I include in the groovy classpath in order it to work correctly*

Comment: I've no idea - I never had that problem. Looks like a candidate for a separate SO question.

Comment: No, it was my fault. I was using "groovy script", and not "system groovy script".

Comment: I am getting the following error `You attempted to use a method 'hudson' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 18, column 29.
           thisBuild.setResult(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)`